# mail function return false when add html content type

Tags: php, email, yii

```
  function sendEmail($to,$subject,$message,$headers=false){
    $from = "app@boutiqueplatter.com";
    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from ) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    try
    {
        if(mail($to,$subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            $sentEmail = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $sentEmail = false;
        }
        var_dump($headers );
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($message, $code, $previous);
        $sentEmail = false;
    }
    return  $sentEmail;
}
```

This is my function when remove the header
`$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`
Then email send properly, but when add this line mail function return false.
But in local machine working fine

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, add 'From' in end of the Header now its working.

```
function sendEmail($to,$subject,$message,$headers=false){
    $from = "app@boutiqueplatter.com";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . strip_tags($from ) . "\r\n";
    try
    {
        if(mail($to,$subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            $sentEmail = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $sentEmail = false;
        }
        var_dump($headers );
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($message, $code, $previous);
        $sentEmail = false;
    }
    return  $sentEmail;
}
```

Comment: and does it actually work? For me, then "from" is ignored

Comment: Hi John for me it was working its very long time ago, now a days for upgrade may be need some changes.